# Unity3D: need help Rotating character without involving position

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

Using Unity3D 2018.2.8

I'm trying to rotate my character (in first person) without involving/ changing the position.

The camera is attached to the character. So in moving the character, the camera follows.
I want to do a drag type of touch to move the objects rotation in 360 degrees.

Not sure if I'm heading the right way with this code

Also, I should be using `Quaternion` for controlling the rotation?

And `targetToLookAt` is the transform of the object of where the camera located

```
public Camera cameraSelf;
private Transform cameraTransform;
private Vector2 cameraRotation;

void FixedUpdate() {
  //  Camera.transform to be the same as camera targets body
  cameraSelf.transform.position = targetToLookAt.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).position;
  cameraSelf.transform.rotation = targetToLookAt.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).rotation;

  //    Moving camera with Mouse
  float pointer_x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
  float pointer_y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
  //  Using Touch
  pointer_x = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
  pointer_y = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;

  //  Mouse Movement
  cameraRotation.x += pointer_x * moveSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
  cameraRotation.y -= pointer_y * moveSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

  //  Set Rotation of Object
  targetToLookAt.position = cameraRotation;
}
```

Comment: So you want something like Bedrock Edition Minecraft camera rotation, not Java Edition Minecraft camera rotation? (In Bedrock you need to move the camera with your fingers to look around, but Java edition, the camera is sorta-attached to the mouse, and moves with it.) Don't use quaternions, they're weird, instead use transform.eulerAngles, as this is alike to the rotation you see in the inspector menu.

Comment: yeah like bedrock, if I want the camera to look left I would drag the screen from left to right, only the rotation

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having trouble. All you should have to do is rotate the player.

Comment: He has to rotate the player based on their original rotation then add/subtract the x,y eulers based on the difference of the mouse x1,y1 and the final x2,y2 only if the mouse was pressed and moved.

Comment: @crazicrafter1 no idea on how to do this

Comment: Dont tie the x rotation with the x pointer, as that will rotate your character up when you swipe right. 
x:
`cameraRotation.x += pointer_y * moveSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; `
y:

`cameraRotation.y -= pointer_x * moveSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;`

And is this on a mobile device or pc since I see an [Input.touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html)

Comment: If you are on mobile then the [simulated mouse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-simulateMouseWithTouches.html) should be enabled by default. You can then use [this](https://pastebin.com/dQCKM4pa) script.

Comment: I tried that script, nor a touch or a mouse get recognized. Object stays untouched.